# HTML: what is creating border on this webpage

Tags: html

I'm trying to understand this webpage:
http://www.canadianliving.com/food/slow_cooker_beef_stew.php

It is divided into several sections where each section has a border around it. For example, to the right of the title "Slow-Cooker Beef Stew" is an image "tested till perfect". Immediately to the right of this is a border, which separates it from an advertisement. This border extends down and separates the section from the "Related Content" section below.

But what is making the border? I am using Chrome's Inspect Element, Computed Style, but none of the tags seem to have a border-style. What else can create a border?

(I'm not looking for the best way to make a border; I need to understand how other pages do it.)

EDIT:
Based on people's answers, I tried the html below, which is not working. I don't get how an image in a parent div is repeated in each child div in such a way that it fits exactly along the border.

```
<div style = "float:left;background-image:url('http://www.canadianliving.com/media/images/background_02.png?201206051535');background-clip:border-box;background-origin:padding-box;background-repeat:repeat-y;" >

  <div style = "float:left;width:300px;background-clip:border-box;background-origin:padding-box;padding-left:8px">hello</div>

  <div style = "float:left;width:300px;background-clip:border-box;background-origin:padding-box;padding-left:8px">there</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's a [background image](http://www.canadianliving.com/media/images/background_02.png?201206051535) on `#content_container`.

Comment: It was done via a background-image: `#content_container { 
background: url("http://www.canadianliving.com/media/images/background_02.png?201206051535") 605px 0px repeat-y transparent; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is set on the `div#right_col` where the ads are. They have a `padding-left` of 8px (width of the shadow background image) and a `background` set on `content-container` with `url('/media/images/background_02.png') 0 630px repeat-y`.

Comment: This is not working for me. I am editing the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.canadianliving.com/media/images/background_02.png?201206051535

Its an image, not a border, remove the image to get rid of the 'border'.

I deduced this by selecting the container element and reviewing the css background property,
for future reference.

Here an example:

```
<style>

    div#test {

        height:800px;
        width:800px;
        background:url(http://www.canadianliving.com/media/images/background_02.png?201206051535) top right repeat-y #676767;
    }
</style>

<div id="test">TestDiv<div>
```

Keep in mind, this is a rough sketch of what it should look like. I'm not planning on learning you this without some effort. Try w3schools for an html / css tutorial.

I'm betting we all did this kind of research and a lot of trying before trying to submit to these kind of forums.

Happy coding, good luck!

D.

Comment: The image fits exactly so the contents are inside the picture showing the border?

Comment: It is tiled down to achieve this. CSS: background:url([image-url])repeat-y;

Comment: I'm not getting that to work. I edited the question with what I tried.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I totally don't get how an image in a parent div is repeated in each child div in such a way that it fits exactly along the border. This is what I tried in my question edit above. I can make a single div and get the image to show up, like you did. I did test quite a bit and do fine with other css!

Answer (score 0):

basically, it is a background url that is used as a shadow border. Please look at the CSS of `#content_container` in firebug/chrome inspect element.

It is not a border but used as a seperator.